# How to `tee` dropping all CR lines only in the file but not stdout?

Tags: text-processing, newlines, tee

When using e.g. `rsync`, I'd like to `tee` its output such that I can both view the current progress live, and have a log for later. Using just piping `| tee logfile` the logfile will contain many lines à la

```
0 files...<CR>
100 files...<CR>
200 files...<CR>
```

Where the carriage-return `<CR>` is used to have the live output replace the current line. For the `stdout` part of `tee` this is exactly the desired behavior, but is there any way to have the logfile drop anything between a `<CR>` and the last `<LF>`? (I'm not asking for a `rsync` specific answer, that's just the example!) Maybe some `sed`-piping in between?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
... | tee /dev/stderr | grep -v $'\r' > logfile
```

Or:

```
.... | tee >(grep -v $'\r' > logfile)
```

Which would effectively remove that *progress* line in the case of `rsync`. `$'...'` and `>(...)` are ksh syntax also supported by bash and zsh, but not standard `sh`.

Comment: The `>(...)` syntax (how can one even _google_ for that?) doesn't seem to work correctly with bash - `echo test >(echo)` yields `test /dev/fd63`... But the `$'...'` syntax (isn't that part of `grep`'s syntax and not `*sh`?) works perfecty, thanks!

Comment: Yes, >(...) is called _process substitution_ and is expanded by the shell to a file path. That path, when open for writing by the application (typically `tee` opens it, but `echo` doesn't) leads to a `pipe` whose other end is _read_ by the command inside the brackets. You can learn about it in your shell's manual. Try `man bash` or `info bash`.

Comment: Ah, I think now I get it. My test command causes `>(echo)` to run `echo` (yielding a newline and basically ignoring the pipe) and return `/dev/fd63` such that the outer command is `echo test /dev/fd63`. [tldp.org documents it, too](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html). Very interesting mechanism

Comment: side note: mingw/msys don't support process substitution and `/dev/stderr` doesn't exist either. At least `/dev/stdout` can be replaced by `CON`